# custom field link button for different brand

Tags: php, wordpress

i m creating a wordpress theme for mobiles in which i used a custom field with name of "brand". and add three type of brand value LG, Nokia, and Sony..

**Then how to create three separate link buttons for these three type of values which show all other post for same brand value.**

```
   <a href="#"><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'brand', true ); ?>
        <?php _e( '', 'mobilewebsite' ); ?></a>

    <li><a href="#">Nokia</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LG</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sony</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the brand custom field is a meta value for posts, you can use this code to echo each brand field.

```html
<?php  

// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'post_type'     => array( 'post' ),
    'post_status'   => array( 'publish' ),
    'meta_query'    => array(
        array(
            'key'   => 'brand',
        ),
    ),
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        ?>
        <a href="#">
            <?php echo get_field('brand'); ?>
        </a>
        <?php
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_field()...... this error show at line <?php echo get_field('brand'); ?>